# Angular Directive Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: angular, build, directive

When I run "ng build --prod" to build my angular app, It throw an error as "/folio-header.component.html(25,11): Directive InputNumberOnlyDirective, Expected 1 arguments, but got 0."

This is the html code:

```
<input inputNumberOnly class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="folioDto.folioVolume" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

This is the Directive:

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[inputNumberOnly]'
})
export class InputNumberOnlyDirective {

  constructor() {
  }

  @HostListener('keypress') onkeypress(e) {
    let event = e || window.event;
    if (event) {
      return this.isNumberKey(event);
    }
  }

  isNumberKey(event) {
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: you has a typo error, is: `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`

Comment: It is my mistake when I'm adding to the question. thank you for showing it. :)

Comment: sorry,  Aruna, I don't take account. Look your HostListener, you need pass the event, see the e.g. inthe docs: https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener#usage-notes, so `@HostListener('keypress',[$event]) onkeypress(e){...}`

Comment: Thanks Eliseo. It's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are defining a function that requires the listener event at

```
@HostListener('keypress') onkeypress(e) {
```

You can simple fix this by specifying the event argument by adding

```
@HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onkeypress(e) {
```